# How to stage a subproject with playframework

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have a Build file with several subprojects the dependencies look somewhat like this:

*A* is the main project.
*B* depends on *A*.
*C* depends on *B*.

Now I want to stage the subproject *C*. I tried using "clean compile stage" but that doesn't work. when I use the script generated in modules/C/target/start to start the application, project *B* gets started.

How can I start project *C*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the command line of play, you can switch projects.
With the command `projects` you'll see all your subprojects A, B and C.
With `project C` you'll go to C.
Not sure if you can do that outside of play.

Comment: actually thats what I did. I used play "project C" clean compile stage. But it still runs the project B.

I wondered how the runtime knows which project to start? The start script in the main and the subproject are the same.